# Visual Studio 2015 full completely offline distributive

Tags: visual-studio, installation, offline, visual-studio-2015, iso

I'm wondering is there a way to download all external components of VS 2015 (Apache Cordova, Android SDK, Python tools, lots of JS libs etc) to create a complete and offline installer? Preferably I want to find a way to create such "distro" automatically (by running 1-2 commands).

I don't have internet on my work machine and googling, downloading and installing all external dependencies by hand is tedious and I'm not so sure that VS will see them after installation.

PS: Rant - previous VS releases that included all software components in ISO were better.

PPS: This is a complete copy of the question on serverfault - https://serverfault.com/questions/707871/visual-studio-2015-full-completely-offline-distributive because I thought that installation questions are better suited there... Looks like I was wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the layout switch

1. After you download the update executable from the MSDN website to a location on your file system, run the following command at a command prompt:  /layout.
   This command downloads all the packages for the installation.
   By using the /layout switch, you can download all the core installation packages, not just the ones that apply to the download machine. This approach gives you all the files that you need to run this update anywhere and may be useful if you want to install components that weren't installed originally.
2. After you run the command, you should be prompted for the download location. Enter the location, and then choose Download.
3. When the package download is successful, you should see a Visual Studio screen that says Setup Successful! All specified components have been acquired successfully.
4. In the file location that you specified, find the executable file and the package folder. This is everything you need to copy to a shared location or install media.
5. You can now run the installation from the file location or the install media.

Read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#bkmk_offline)

Comment: this is useless if you have expensive and slow internet :(